# Load a website with an added javascript

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, safari

What I'm trying to do is load Facebook.com in safari, except with my added javascript which regularly checks for received chat messages and translates them.
How do I got about this without making a safari extension, or using grease kit?
I guess what I need to do is load Facebook.com, but with my script tacked/"injected" in the head of the document...

Comment: well i mean, for example if i go to Facebook.com right now, and open the safari console, i can type in some javascript and execute it on the page...
but i need a more streamlined/programmatic way...

Comment: so this is just for your personal use? there are safari plugins that will allow you to use greasemonkey scripts and also plugins that will allow you to code in your own scripts. For example - http://www.simplehelp.net/2007/11/14/how-to-run-greasemonkey-scripts-in-safari/

Comment: okay, i get that... "without making a safari extension, or using grease kit?"

Comment: Any reason grease is out? It is widely supported and works on Safari. Sorry, I don't know of any other plugins that perform scripting for you.

Comment: Hmmmm, write your own browser?  Seriously, isn't the whole purpose of an extension to do exactly what you are asking for?

Comment: right, but i don't want to make an extension... this needs to be included in a mac app, and apple's sandboxing would not allow me to load an extension...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak for Safari, but in Firefox there is a marvelous addon called [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) that does exactly what you want: execute arbitrary JS of your choosing/creation on arbitrary websites. I use it on google to keep down their tracking of my clicks.

**Update:**

I don't know why you have these constraints. *Not* using GreaseMonkey means doing a huge amount of work, and for what purpose? I suppose you could use any one of a number of proxy servers and have it do this for you automatically, but that would mean:

1. Finding and setting up the server.
2. Running all of your requests through it. This is not only slower, but it also may play havoc with things like streaming video, etc.

Bottom line: You can't change Safari itself so you either use an existing addon, make one yourself (no easy feat), or use a proxy. Life is too short as it is, so go grab GreaseMonkey and be done with it.

Comment: "without making a safari extension, or using grease kit?"